# mysqldump with php to export a single table

Tags: mysql

I want to export one table from my database into a .sql file using `mysqldump`.

My code almost works:

```
$problem = ' --databases '.$db_name;

$cmd  = 'mysqldump';
$cmd .= ' --host='.$dbhost;
$cmd .= ' --user='.$dbuser;
$cmd .= ' --password='.$dbpass;
$cmd .= $problem;
$cmd .= ' > '.$filename;

shell_exec( $cmd.' '.$filename)
```

This code works fantastic, giving me a dump of the entire database into the file I've specified.

However: Now I only want to get **one** table dumped.

**Let's modify the variable `$problem`:**

*option 1*

```
$problem  = ' --databases '.$db_name.' '.$table_name;
```

**This still dumps the entire DB**

*option 2*

```
$problem  = ' --databases '.$db_name;
$problem .= ' --tables '.$table_name;
```

*option 3*

```
$problem = ' --tables '.$table_name;
```

*option 4*

```
$problem = ' --tables '.$table_name.' '.$db_name;
```

*option 5*

```
$problem = ' '.$db_name.' '.$table_name;
```

**Options 2 through 5 result in only some kind of header-like information being output into the file:**

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.58, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: mysql.mydomain.com    Database: [$db_name or $table_name]
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.29-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Reading the [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-summary) hasn't given me any more insight...

Comment: Option 5 appears to be the correct way for a single table.  I noted in the dump example, this portion: `Database: [$db_name or $table_name]` ... as if it took the variables literally without evaluation. Maybe echo the `$cmd` value before calling `shell_exec` call to see how the cmd looks beforehand.

Comment: That helped my find my error, thank you. I accidentally added filepath 2x when actually executing the command. Which is weird that it caused this behavior where it sometimes dumps the hole database and sometimes only the header...

Comment: `shell_exec( $cmd.' '.$filename)` right there is my error. It needs to be `shell_exec($cmd)`

Comment: Good news, and thanks for reporting the findings!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was this:

`shell_exec( $cmd.' '.$filename);`

has to be changed to

`shell_exec( $cmd);`

`$filename` had already been included into `$cmd`.

Once fixed, all the code works as expected.